# React Native Active Image Link Not Working

Tags: reactjs, server, react-native, web-hosting

So I am having a really weird problem.  I'm not sure if it's my server thats is causing the problem or it's my react code.  Right now I am trying to load an image using this code in my app:

```
<Image style={styles.image}
  source={{uri:'http://www.test.com/admin/images/profile/'+this.props.active.bid+'.jpg'}}
/>
```

The link is a correct link and image displays if you go to the actual link, however in my app it doesn't display the image. 
The file permissions on the image are 644 and I have 1 image working, however whenever I try to remove that image from the server or rename it to be the correct image for the 2nd profile it still shows up for the 1st profile and not the 2nd.  If I delete the image the app still receives it for the 1st profile even though it shouldn't show up, if I go to the weblink the image doesn't appear.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: could you provide an example on rnplay.org?

Comment: I have similar weird issues with images. Try to reset your simulator. On iOS its something like "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings..."

Comment: @dv3 thank you that fixed it.  That is really weird that you'd have to reset the simulator in order for it to pick up the images coming from links.  Toss up a response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem you just have to reset the simulator.

To do this go to Simulator - > Reset Content and Settings...

This deletes all of the data on the device so beware if there is something on there that you cannot restore.